# Subscript out of range when appending items to array in excel vba

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have an array in excel vba and I would like to append 3 items to the end of the array but i got a subscript out of range error whenever i run my code.

First, I split the "rtv" array and I want to append "class", "age" and "address to the end of the "rtv" array but i receive an error.

My code looks like this:

```
rtv = Split(Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Name,Sheets("Properties").Range("B1:C7"), 2, False), ",") 
    rtv(UBound(rtv)) = "Class"
    rtv(UBound(rtv) + 1) = "Age"
    rtv(UBound(rtv) + 2) = "Address"

    For i = LBound(rtv) To UBound(rtv)
        rtv(i) = Chr(34) & rtv(i) & Chr(34) & ":" & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & ";"
    Next i
```

And this is how I declare my array:

```
Dim rtv() As String
Dim i As Long
```

Anyone knows where the error lies ?

Comment: you mean looping ?

Comment: I want to add the three extra elements before the loop

Comment: I think some images might help understand it

Comment: You can't just add items to an array like that. You need to have a second array, declare that to the appopriate size using `Redim` and transfer values into that.

Answer (score 1):

In `VBA` the size of an array cannot be increased simply by adding elements to it. The array must be `ReDim`ed. If the contents needs to pe preserved while `ReDim`, then  `ReDim Preserve`must be used.

Example (simplified `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Name,Sheets("Properties").Range("B1:C7"), 2, False)` by using a string)

```
Sub test()

 Dim rtv() As String

 sVLookupResult = "a,b,c"

 rtv = Split(sVLookupResult, ",")

 lrtvLength = UBound(rtv)

 ReDim Preserve rtv(lrtvLength + 3)

 rtv(lrtvLength + 1) = "Class"
 rtv(lrtvLength + 2) = "Age"
 rtv(lrtvLength + 3) = "Address"

 For i = LBound(rtv) To UBound(rtv)
  rtv(i) = Chr(34) & rtv(i) & Chr(34) & ":" & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & ";"
 Next i

 MsgBox Join(rtv)

End Sub
```